# How to define advance function (like laravel components)

Tags: php

I have 2 questions:
Q1. I have a function:

```
namespace Core;
class MyRoute {
  static function get($slug, $action) {
   // code  
  }
}
```

i want to define this function like laravel router:

```
$checkLogin = function() {
    if(Sentry::check()) return false;
    return true;
};
MyRoute::get('foo/bar', function() {
  //code
})->before($checkLogin);
```

How to get $action and handle ?

Q2: I want to use Silex application (route), and i want to use my static class, callback to $app

```
namespace Core;
class MyRoute {
  static function get($slug, $name) {
   $app->get('/home/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
     return 'Home';
   });  
  }
}
```

How to use if multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

To use anonymous function passed as parameter simply:

```
function get($slug, $action)
{
   $action();
}
```

with parameters it becomes like this:

```
function get($slug, $action)
{
   $action( 42 );
}
get( 13 , function($x){echo $x;} );
```

Comment: Ok. and how to add before check ? ->before($checkLogin)

Comment: "How can function return anonymous function as result" is your question? Similarly: return function($foo){echo $foo;} ;